# <Python> input multiple arguments in function

Tags: python

This is how I have to pass argument

```
p = Column(fg[0,], fg[1,], fg[2,], fg[3,], fg[4,], fg[5,])
show(p)
```

But instead I want to do something like

```
p = Column(fg[0,] : fg[5,])
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you really want to pass it all of the first 6 (0-5, inclusive) arguments, you can probably use [tuple unpacking](https://www.guru99.com/python-tuples-tutorial-comparing-deleting-slicing-keys-unpacking.html#1):

```
p = Column(*fg[:6,])
show(p)
```

Here a slightly more complete example using `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x0, x1):
    print(x0, x1)

x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]])
f(*x[:2,])
# [0 1] [2 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the children argument. `fg` must be a list of figures or plots:

```
p = Column(children=fg)
show(p)
```